# Not sure what's wrong? Batch code

Tags: batch-file

I've been messing around trying to build a game with maps and a movement system in batch, but after I choose "Play" it freezes, then closes. I took a slow motion recording of the error (it closed even when I inserted pause to see the error), and saw that it's telling me my echo command syntax is wrong, and trying closed tests, only this code does it. I wrote a new code that I just set a few variables and echoed them, and it worked just fine. not sure what's going on and I've tried it on three different computers. Anyways, here is the code:

```
    @echo off
color a
:begin

SET /a "FLR1"=0
SET /a "FLR2"=0
SET /a "FLR3"=0
SET /a "FLR4"=0
SET /a "FLR5"=0
SET /a "FLR6"=0
SET /a "FLR7"=0
SET /a "FLR8"=0
SET /a "FLR9"=0
SET /a "FLR10"=0
SET /a "FLR11"=0
SET /a "FLR12"=0
SET /a "FLR13"=0
SET /a "FLR14"=0
SET /a "FLR15"=0
SET /a "FLR16"=0
SET /a "FLR17"=0
SET /a "FLR18"=0
SET /a "FLR19"=0
SET /a "FLR20"=0
SET /a "FLR21"=0
SET /a "FLR22"=0
SET /a "FLR23"=0
SET /a "FLR24"=0
SET /a "FLR25"=0
echo --------------------------
echo GGGGG  AAA  MM MM EEEEE !!
echo G     A   A M M M E     !!
echo G  GG AAAAA M   M EEE   !!
echo G   G A   A M   M E     
echo GGGGG A   A M   M EEEEE xx
echo --------------------------
echo KURTIS' GAMES:
echo ARIAN UNDERGROUND (ALPHA)
echo --------------------------
echo 1. PLAY
echo 2. LOAD (INACTIVE)
echo 3. OPTIONS (INACTIVE)
echo 0. EXIT
CHOICE /c 1230 /n /m "ENTER SELECTION"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ACTIVE
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO LOAD
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO OPTIONS
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO END

:PLAY
GOTO ACTIVE
    :ACTIVE
REM ---------------------------------------------------------FLOOR 1 START
SET v0001=X
SET v0002=X
SET v0003=X
SET v0004=X
SET v0005=X
SET v0006=X
SET v0007=X
SET v0008=X
SET v0009=X
SET v0010=X
SET v0011=X
SET v0012=X
SET v0013=X
SET v0014=X
SET v0015=X
SET v0016=X
SET v0017=X
SET v0018=X
SET v0019=X
SET v0020=X
SET v0021=X
SET v0022=X
SET v0023=X
SET v0024=X
SET v0025=X
SET v0026=X
SET v0027=X
SET v0028=X
SET v0029=X
SET v0030=X
SET v0031=X
SET v0032=X
SET v0033=X
SET v0034=X
SET v0035=X
SET v0036=X
SET v0037=X
SET v0038=X
SET v0039=X
SET v0040=X
SET v0041=X
SET v0042=X
SET v0043=X
SET v0044=X
SET v0045=X
SET v0046=X
SET v0047=X
SET v0048=X
SET v0049=X
SET v0050=X
SET v0101=X
SET v0102=X
SET v0103=X
SET v0104=X
SET v0105=X
SET v0106=X
SET v0107=X
SET v0108=X
SET v0109=X
SET v0110=X
SET v0111=X
SET v0112=X
SET v0113=X
SET v0114=X
SET v0115=X
SET v0116=X
SET v0117=X
SET v0118=X
SET v0119=X
SET v0120=X
SET v0121=X
SET v0122=X
SET v0123=X
SET v0124=X
SET v0125=X
SET v0126=X
SET v0127=X
SET v0128=X
SET v0129=X
SET v0130=X
SET v0131=X
SET v0132=X
SET v0133=X
SET v0134=X
SET v0135=X
SET v0136=X
SET v0137=X
SET v0138=X
SET v0139=X
SET v0140=X
SET v0141=X
SET v0142=X
SET v0143=X
SET v0144=X
SET v0145=X
SET v0146=X
SET v0147=X
SET v0148=X
SET v0149=X
SET v0150=X
SET v0201=X
SET v0202=X
SET v0203=X
SET v0204=X
SET v0205=X
SET v0206=X
SET v0207=X
SET v0208=X
SET v0209=X
SET v0210=X
SET v0211=X
SET v0212=X
SET v0213=X
SET v0214=X
SET v0215=X
SET v0216=X
SET v0217=X
SET v0218=X
SET v0219=X
SET v0220=X
SET v0221=X
SET v0222=X
SET v0223=X
SET v0224=X
SET v0225=X
SET v0226=X
SET v0227=X
SET v0228=X
SET v0229=X
SET v0230=X
SET v0231=X
SET v0232=X
SET v0233=X
SET v0234=X
SET v0235=X
SET v0236=X
SET v0237=X
SET v0238=X
SET v0239=X
SET v0240=X
SET v0241=X
SET v0242=X
SET v0243=X
SET v0244=X
SET v0245=X
SET v0246=X
SET v0247=X
SET v0248=X
SET v0249=X
SET v0250=X
SET v0301=X
SET v0302=X
SET v0303=X
SET v0304=X
SET v0305=X
SET v0306=X
SET v0307=X
SET v0308=X
SET v0309=X
SET v0310=X
SET v0311=X
SET v0312=X
SET v0313=X
SET v0314=X
SET v0315=X
SET v0316=X
SET v0317=X
SET v0318=X
SET v0319=X
SET v0320=X
SET v0321=X
SET v0322=X
SET v0323=X
SET v0324=X
SET v0325=X
SET v0326=X
SET v0327=X
SET v0328=X
SET v0329=X
SET v0330=X
SET v0331=X
SET v0332=X
SET v0333=X
SET v0334=X
SET v0335=X
SET v0336=X
SET v0337=X
SET v0338=X
SET v0339=X
SET v0340=X
SET v0341=X
SET v0342=X
SET v0343=X
SET v0344=X
SET v0345=X
SET v0346=X
SET v0347=X
SET v0348=X
SET v0349=X
SET v0350=X
SET v0401=X
SET v0402=X
SET v0403=X
SET v0404=X
SET v0405=X
SET v0406=X
SET v0407=X
SET v0408=X
SET v0409=X
SET v0410=X
SET v0411=X
SET v0412=X
SET v0413=X
SET v0414=X
SET v0415=X
SET v0416=X
SET v0417=X
SET v0418=X
SET v0419=X
SET v0420=X
SET v0421=X
SET v0422=X
SET v0423=X
SET v0424=X
SET v0425=X
SET v0426=X
SET v0427=X
SET v0428=X
SET v0429=X
SET v0430=X
SET v0431=X
SET v0432=X
SET v0433=X
SET v0434=X
SET v0435=X
SET v0436=X
SET v0437=X
SET v0438=X
SET v0439=X
SET v0440=X
SET v0441=X
SET v0442=X
SET v0443=X
SET v0444=X
SET v0445=X
SET v0446=X
SET v0447=X
SET v0448=X
SET v0449=X
SET v0450=X
SET v0501=X
SET v0502=X
SET v0503=X
SET v0504=X
SET v0505=X
SET v0506=X
SET v0507=X
SET v0508=X
SET v0509=X
SET v0510=X
SET v0511=X
SET v0512=X
SET v0513=X
SET v0514=X
SET v0515=X
SET v0516=X
SET v0517=X
SET v0518=X
SET v0519=X
SET v0520=X
SET v0521=X
SET v0522=X
SET v0523=X
SET v0524=X
SET v0525=X
SET v0526=X
SET v0527=X
SET v0528=X
SET v0529=X
SET v0530=X
SET v0531=X
SET v0532=X
SET v0533=X
SET v0534=X
SET v0535=X
SET v0536=X
SET v0537=X
SET v0538=X
SET v0539=X
SET v0540=X
SET v0541=X
SET v0542=X
SET v0543=X
SET v0544=X
SET v0545=X
SET v0546=X
SET v0547=X
SET v0548=X
SET v0549=X
SET v0550=X
SET v0601=X
SET v0602=X
SET v0603=X
SET v0604=X
SET v0605=X
SET v0606=X
SET v0607=X
SET v0608=X
SET v0609=X
SET v0610=X
SET v0611=X
SET v0612=X
SET v0613=X
SET v0614=X
SET v0615=X
SET v0616=X
SET v0617=X
SET v0618=X
SET v0619=X
SET v0620=X
SET v0621=X
SET v0622=X
SET v0623=X
SET v0624=X
SET v0625=X
SET v0626=X
SET v0627=X
SET v0628=X
SET v0629=X
SET v0630=X
SET v0631=X
SET v0632=X
SET v0633=X
SET v0634=X
SET v0635=X
SET v0636=X
SET v0637=X
SET v0638=X
SET v0639=X
SET v0640=X
SET v0641=X
SET v0642=X
SET v0643=X
SET v0644=X
SET v0645=X
SET v0646=X
SET v0647=X
SET v0648=X
SET v0649=X
SET v0650=X
SET v0701=X
SET v0702=X
SET v0703=X
SET v0704=X
SET v0705=X
SET v0706=X
SET v0707=X
SET v0708=X
SET v0709=X
SET v0710=X
SET v0711=X
SET v0712=X
SET v0713=X
SET v0714=X
SET v0715=X
SET v0716=X
SET v0717=X
SET v0718=X
SET v0719=X
SET v0720=X
SET v0721=X
SET v0722=X
SET v0723=X
SET v0724=X
SET v0725=X
SET v0726=X
SET v0727=X
SET v0728=X
SET v0729=X
SET v0730=X
SET v0731=X
SET v0732=X
SET v0733=X
SET v0734=X
SET v0735=X
SET v0736=X
SET v0737=X
SET v0738=X
SET v0739=X
SET v0740=X
SET v0741=X
SET v0742=X
SET v0743=X
SET v0744=X
SET v0745=X
SET v0746=X
SET v0747=X
SET v0748=X
SET v0749=X
SET v0750=X
SET v0801=X
SET v0802=X
SET v0803=X
SET v0804=X
SET v0805=X
SET v0806=X
SET v0807=X
SET v0808=X
SET v0809=X
SET v0810=X
SET v0811=X
SET v0812=X
SET v0813=X
SET v0814=X
SET v0815=X
SET v0816=X
SET v0817=X
SET v0818=X
SET v0819=X
SET v0820=X
SET v0821=X
SET v0822=X
SET v0823=X
SET v0824=X
SET v0825=X
SET v0826=X
SET v0827=X
SET v0828=X
SET v0829=X
SET v0830=X
SET v0831=X
SET v0832=X
SET v0833=X
SET v0834=X
SET v0835=X
SET v0836=X
SET v0837=X
SET v0838=X
SET v0839=X
SET v0840=X
SET v0841=X
SET v0842=X
SET v0843=X
SET v0844=X
SET v0845=X
SET v0846=X
SET v0847=X
SET v0848=X
SET v0849=X
SET v0850=X
SET v0901=X
SET v0902=X
SET v0903=X
SET v0904=X
SET v0905=X
SET v0906=X
SET v0907=X
SET v0908=X
SET v0909=X
SET v0910=X
SET v0911=X
SET v0912=X
SET v0913=X
SET v0914=X
SET v0915=X
SET v0916=X
SET v0917=X
SET v0918=X
SET v0919=X
SET v0920=X
SET v0921=X
SET v0922=X
SET v0923=X
SET v0924=X
SET v0925=X
SET v0926=X
SET v0927=X
SET v0928=X
SET v0929=X
SET v0930=X
SET v0931=X
SET v0932=X
SET v0933=X
SET v0934=X
SET v0935=X
SET v0936=X
SET v0937=X
SET v0938=X
SET v0939=X
SET v0940=X
SET v0941=X
SET v0942=X
SET v0943=X
SET v0944=X
SET v0945=X
SET v0946=X
SET v0947=X
SET v0948=X
SET v0949=X
SET v0950=X
SET v1001=X
SET v1002=X
SET v1003=X
SET v1004=X
SET v1005=X
SET v1006=X
SET v1007=X
SET v1008=X
SET v1009=X
SET v1010=X
SET v1011=X
SET v1012=X
SET v1013=X
SET v1014=X
SET v1015=X
SET v1016=X
SET v1017=X
SET v1018=X
SET v1019=X
SET v1020=X
SET v1021=X
SET v1022=X
SET v1023=X
SET v1024=X
SET v1025=X
SET v1026=X
SET v1027=X
SET v1028=X
SET v1029=X
SET v1030=X
SET v1031=X
SET v1032=X
SET v1033=X
SET v1034=X
SET v1035=X
SET v1036=X
SET v1037=X
SET v1038=X
SET v1039=X
SET v1040=X
SET v1041=X
SET v1042=X
SET v1043=X
SET v1044=X
SET v1045=X
SET v1046=X
SET v1047=X
SET v1048=X
SET v1049=X
SET v1050=X
SET v1101=X
SET v1102=X
SET v1103=X
SET v1104=X
SET v1105=X
SET v1106=X
SET v1107=X
SET v1108=X
SET v1109=X
SET v1110=X
SET v1111=X
SET v1112=X
SET v1113=X
SET v1114=X
SET v1115=X
SET v1116=X
SET v1117=X
SET v1118=X
SET v1119=X
SET v1120=X
SET v1121=X
SET v1122=X
SET v1123=X
SET v1124=X
SET v1125=X
SET v1126=X
SET v1127=X
SET v1128=X
SET v1129=X
SET v1130=X
SET v1131=X
SET v1132=X
SET v1133=X
SET v1134=X
SET v1135=X
SET v1136=X
SET v1137=X
SET v1138=X
SET v1139=X
SET v1140=X
SET v1141=X
SET v1142=X
SET v1143=X
SET v1144=X
SET v1145=X
SET v1146=X
SET v1147=X
SET v1148=X
SET v1149=X
SET v1150=X
SET v1201=X
SET v1202=X
SET v1203=X
SET v1204=X
SET v1205=X
SET v1206=X
SET v1207=X
SET v1208=X
SET v1209=X
SET v1210=X
SET v1211=X
SET v1212=X
SET v1213=X
SET v1214=X
SET v1215=X
SET v1216=X
SET v1217=X
SET v1218=X
SET v1219=X
SET v1220=X
SET v1221=X
SET v1222=X
SET v1223=X
SET v1224=X
SET v1225=X
SET v1226=X
SET v1227=X
SET v1228=X
SET v1229=X
SET v1230=X
SET v1231=X
SET v1232=X
SET v1233=X
SET v1234=X
SET v1235=X
SET v1236=X
SET v1237=X
SET v1238=X
SET v1239=X
SET v1240=X
SET v1241=X
SET v1242=X
SET v1243=X
SET v1244=X
SET v1245=X
SET v1246=X
SET v1247=X
SET v1248=X
SET v1249=X
SET v1250=X
SET v1301=X
SET v1302=X
SET v1303=X
SET v1304=X
SET v1305=X
SET v1306=X
SET v1307=X
SET v1308=X
SET v1309=X
SET v1310=X
SET v1311=X
SET v1312=X
SET v1313=X
SET v1314=X
SET v1315=X
SET v1316=X
SET v1317=X
SET v1318=X
SET v1319=X
SET v1320=X
SET v1321=X
SET v1322=X
SET v1323=X
SET v1324=X
SET v1325=X
SET v1326=X
SET v1327=X
SET v1328=X
SET v1329=X
SET v1330=X
SET v1331=X
SET v1332=X
SET v1333=X
SET v1334=X
SET v1335=X
SET v1336=X
SET v1337=X
SET v1338=X
SET v1339=X
SET v1340=X
SET v1341=X
SET v1342=X
SET v1343=X
SET v1344=X
SET v1345=X
SET v1346=X
SET v1347=X
SET v1348=X
SET v1349=X
SET v1350=X
SET v1401=X
SET v1402=X
SET v1403=X
SET v1404=X
SET v1405=X
SET v1406=X
SET v1407=X
SET v1408=X
SET v1409=X
SET v1410=X
SET v1411=X
SET v1412=X
SET v1413=X
SET v1414=X
SET v1415=X
SET v1416=X
SET v1417=X
SET v1418=X
SET v1419=X
SET v1420=X
SET v1421=X
SET v1422=X
SET v1423=X
SET v1424=X
SET v1425=X
SET v1426=X
SET v1427=X
SET v1428=X
SET v1429=X
SET v1430=X
SET v1431=X
SET v1432=X
SET v1433=X
SET v1434=X
SET v1435=X
SET v1436=X
SET v1437=X
SET v1438=X
SET v1439=X
SET v1440=X
SET v1441=X
SET v1442=X
SET v1443=X
SET v1444=X
SET v1445=X
SET v1446=X
SET v1447=X
SET v1448=X
SET v1449=X
SET v1450=X
SET v1501=X
SET v1502=X
SET v1503=X
SET v1504=X
SET v1505=X
SET v1506=X
SET v1507=X
SET v1508=X
SET v1509=X
SET v1510=X
SET v1511=X
SET v1512=X
SET v1513=X
SET v1514=X
SET v1515=X
SET v1516=X
SET v1517=X
SET v1518=X
SET v1519=X
SET v1520=X
SET v1521=X
SET v1522=X
SET v1523=X
SET v1524=X
SET v1525=X
SET v1526=X
SET v1527=X
SET v1528=X
SET v1529=X
SET v1530=X
SET v1531=X
SET v1532=X
SET v1533=X
SET v1534=X
SET v1535=X
SET v1536=X
SET v1537=X
SET v1538=X
SET v1539=X
SET v1540=X
SET v1541=X
SET v1542=X
SET v1543=X
SET v1544=X
SET v1545=X
SET v1546=X
SET v1547=X
SET v1548=X
SET v1549=X
SET v1550=X
SET v1601=X
SET v1602=X
SET v1603=X
SET v1604=X
SET v1605=X
SET v1606=X
SET v1607=X
SET v1608=X
SET v1609=X
SET v1610=X
SET v1611=X
SET v1612=X
SET v1613=X
SET v1614=X
SET v1615=X
SET v1616=X
SET v1617=X
SET v1618=X
SET v1619=X
SET v1620=X
SET v1621=X
SET v1622=X
SET v1623=X
SET v1624=X
SET v1625=X
SET v1626=X
SET v1627=X
SET v1628=X
SET v1629=X
SET v1630=X
SET v1631=X
SET v1632=X
SET v1633=X
SET v1634=X
SET v1635=X
SET v1636=X
SET v1637=X
SET v1638=X
SET v1639=X
SET v1640=X
SET v1641=X
SET v1642=X
SET v1643=X
SET v1644=X
SET v1645=X
SET v1646=X
SET v1647=X
SET v1648=X
SET v1649=X
SET v1650=X
SET v1701=X
SET v1702=X
SET v1703=X
SET v1704=X
SET v1705=X
SET v1706=X
SET v1707=X
SET v1708=X
SET v1709=X
SET v1710=X
SET v1711=X
SET v1712=X
SET v1713=X
SET v1714=X
SET v1715=X
SET v1716=X
SET v1717=X
SET v1718=X
SET v1719=X
SET v1720=X
SET v1721=X
SET v1722=X
SET v1723=X
SET v1724=X
SET v1725=X
SET v1726=X
SET v1727=X
SET v1728=X
SET v1729=X
SET v1730=X
SET v1731=X
SET v1732=X
SET v1733=X
SET v1734=X
SET v1735=X
SET v1736=X
SET v1737=X
SET v1738=X
SET v1739=X
SET v1740=X
SET v1741=X
SET v1742=X
SET v1743=X
SET v1744=X
SET v1745=X
SET v1746=X
SET v1747=X
SET v1748=X
SET v1749=X
SET v1750=X
SET v1801=X
SET v1802=X
SET v1803=X
SET v1804=X
SET v1805=X
SET v1806=X
SET v1807=X
SET v1808=X
SET v1809=X
SET v1810=X
SET v1811=X
SET v1812=X
SET v1813=X
SET v1814=X
SET v1815=X
SET v1816=X
SET v1817=X
SET v1818=X
SET v1819=X
SET v1820=X
SET v1821=X
SET v1822=X
SET v1823=X
SET v1824=X
SET v1825=X
SET v1826=X
SET v1827=X
SET v1828=X
SET v1829=X
SET v1830=X
SET v1831=X
SET v1832=X
SET v1833=X
SET v1834=X
SET v1835=X
SET v1836=X
SET v1837=X
SET v1838=X
SET v1839=X
SET v1840=X
SET v1841=X
SET v1842=X
SET v1843=X
SET v1844=X
SET v1845=X
SET v1846=X
SET v1847=X
SET v1848=X
SET v1849=X
SET v1850=X
SET v1901=X
SET v1902=X
SET v1903=X
SET v1904=X
SET v1905=X
SET v1906=X
SET v1907=X
SET v1908=X
SET v1909=X
SET v1910=X
SET v1911=X
SET v1912=X
SET v1913=X
SET v1914=X
SET v1915=X
SET v1916=X
SET v1917=X
SET v1918=X
SET v1919=X
SET v1920=X
SET v1921=X
SET v1922=X
SET v1923=X
SET v1924=X
SET v1925=X
SET v1926=X
SET v1927=X
SET v1928=X
SET v1929=X
SET v1930=X
SET v1931=X
SET v1932=X
SET v1933=X
SET v1934=X
SET v1935=X
SET v1936=X
SET v1937=X
SET v1938=X
SET v1939=X
SET v1940=X
SET v1941=X
SET v1942=X
SET v1943=X
SET v1944=X
SET v1945=X
SET v1946=X
SET v1947=X
SET v1948=X
SET v1949=X
SET v1950=X
SET v2001=X
SET v2002=X
SET v2003=X
SET v2004=X
SET v2005=X
SET v2006=X
SET v2007=X
SET v2008=X
SET v2009=X
SET v2010=X
SET v2011=X
SET v2012=X
SET v2013=X
SET v2014=X
SET v2015=X
SET v2016=X
SET v2017=X
SET v2018=X
SET v2019=X
SET v2020=X
SET v2021=X
SET v2022=X
SET v2023=X
SET v2024=X
SET v2025=X
SET v2026=X
SET v2027=X
SET v2028=X
SET v2029=X
SET v2030=X
SET v2031=X
SET v2032=X
SET v2033=X
SET v2034=X
SET v2035=X
SET v2036=X
SET v2037=X
SET v2038=X
SET v2039=X
SET v2040=X
SET v2041=X
SET v2042=X
SET v2043=X
SET v2044=X
SET v2045=X
SET v2046=X
SET v2047=X
SET v2048=X
SET v2049=X
SET v2050=X


ECHO HEALTH:%HEALTHSTAT% DEPTH:%DEPTHSTAT% KEYS:%KEYSTAT% 
ECHO ____________________________________________________
ECHO |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%v0021%%v0022%%v0023%%v0024%%v0025%%v0026%%v0027%%v0028%%v0029%%v0030%XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
ECHO |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%v0121%%v0122%%v0123%%v0124%%v0125%%v0126%%v0127%%v0128%%v0129%%v0130%XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
ECHO |%v0201%%v0202%%v0203%%v0204%%v0205%%v0206%%v0207%%v0208%%v0209%%v0210%%v0211%%v0212%%v0213%%v0214%%v0215%%v0216%%v0217%%v0218%%v0219%%v0220%%v0221%%v0222%%v0223%%v0224%%v0225%%v0226%%v0227%%v0228%%v0229%%v0230%%v0231%%v0232%%v0233%%v0234%%v0235%%v0236%%v0237%%v0238%%v0239%%v0240%%v0241%%v0242%%v0243%%v0244%%v0245%%v0246%%v0247%%v0248%%v0249%%v0250%|
ECHO |%v0301%%v0302%%v0303%%v0304%%v0305%%v0306%%v0307%%v0308%%v0309%%v0310%%v0311%%v0312%%v0313%%v0314%%v0315%%v0316%%v0317%%v0318%%v0319%%v0320%%v0321%%v0322%%v0323%%v0324%%v0325%%v0326%%v0327%%v0328%%v0329%%v0330%%v0331%%v0332%%v0333%%v0334%%v0335%%v0336%%v0337%%v0338%%v0339%%v0340%%v0341%%v0342%%v0343%%v0344%%v0345%%v0346%%v0347%%v0348%%v0349%%v0350%|
ECHO |%v0401%%v0402%%v0403%%v0404%%v0405%%v0406%%v0407%%v0408%%v0409%%v0410%%v0411%%v0412%%v0413%%v0414%%v0415%%v0416%%v0417%%v0418%%v0419%%v0420%%v0421%%v0422%%v0423%%v0424%%v0425%%v0426%%v0427%%v0428%%v0429%%v0430%%v0431%%v0432%%v0433%%v0434%%v0435%%v0436%%v0437%%v0438%%v0439%%v0440%%v0441%%v0442%%v0443%%v0444%%v0445%%v0446%%v0447%%v0448%%v0449%%v0450%|
ECHO |%v0501%%v0502%%v0503%%v0504%%v0505%%v0506%%v0507%%v0508%%v0509%%v0510%%v0511%%v0512%%v0513%%v0514%%v0515%%v0516%%v0517%%v0518%%v0519%%v0520%%v0521%%v0522%%v0523%%v0524%%v0525%%v0526%%v0527%%v0528%%v0529%%v0530%%v0531%%v0532%%v0533%%v0534%%v0535%%v0536%%v0537%%v0538%%v0539%%v0540%%v0541%%v0542%%v0543%%v0544%%v0545%%v0546%%v0547%%v0548%%v0549%%v0550%|
ECHO |%v0601%%v0602%%v0603%%v0604%%v0605%%v0606%%v0607%%v0608%%v0609%%v0610%%v0611%%v0612%%v0613%%v0614%%v0615%%v0616%%v0617%%v0618%%v0619%%v0620%%v0621%%v0622%%v0623%%v0624%%v0625%%v0626%%v0627%%v0628%%v0629%%v0630%%v0631%%v0632%%v0633%%v0634%%v0635%%v0636%%v0637%%v0638%%v0639%%v0640%%v0641%%v0642%%v0643%%v0644%%v0645%%v0646%%v0647%%v0648%%v0649%%v0650%|
ECHO |%v0701%%v0702%%v0703%%v0704%%v0705%%v0706%%v0707%%v0708%%v0709%%v0710%%v0711%%v0712%%v0713%%v0714%%v0715%%v0716%%v0717%%v0718%%v0719%%v0720%%v0721%%v0722%%v0723%%v0724%%v0725%%v0726%%v0727%%v0728%%v0729%%v0730%%v0731%%v0732%%v0733%%v0734%%v0735%%v0736%%v0737%%v0738%%v0739%%v0740%%v0741%%v0742%%v0743%%v0744%%v0745%%v0746%%v0747%%v0748%%v0749%%v0750%|
ECHO |%v0801%%v0802%%v0803%%v0804%%v0805%%v0806%%v0807%%v0808%%v0809%%v0810%%v0811%%v0812%%v0813%%v0814%%v0815%%v0816%%v0817%%v0818%%v0819%%v0820%%v0821%%v0822%%v0823%%v0824%%v0825%%v0826%%v0827%%v0828%%v0829%%v0830%%v0831%%v0832%%v0833%%v0834%%v0835%%v0836%%v0837%%v0838%%v0839%%v0840%%v0841%%v0842%%v0843%%v0844%%v0845%%v0846%%v0847%%v0848%%v0849%%v0850%|
ECHO |%v0901%%v0902%%v0903%%v0904%%v0905%%v0906%%v0907%%v0908%%v0909%%v0910%%v0911%%v0912%%v0913%%v0914%%v0915%%v0916%%v0917%%v0918%%v0919%%v0920%%v0921%%v0922%%v0923%%v0924%%v0925%%v0926%%v0927%%v0928%%v0929%%v0930%%v0931%%v0932%%v0933%%v0934%%v0935%%v0936%%v0937%%v0938%%v0939%%v0940%%v0941%%v0942%%v0943%%v0944%%v0945%%v0946%%v0947%%v0948%%v0949%%v0950%|
ECHO |%v1001%%v1002%%v1003%%v1004%%v1005%%v1006%%v1007%%v1008%%v1009%%v1010%%v1011%%v1012%%v1013%%v1014%%v1015%%v1016%%v1017%%v1018%%v1019%%v1020%%v1021%%v1022%%v1023%%v1024%%v1025%%v1026%%v1027%%v1028%%v1029%%v1030%%v1031%%v1032%%v1033%%v1034%%v1035%%v1036%%v1037%%v1038%%v1039%%v1040%%v1041%%v1042%%v1043%%v1044%%v1045%%v1046%%v1047%%v1048%%v1049%%v1050%|
ECHO |%v1101%%v1102%%v1103%%v1104%%v1105%%v1106%%v1107%%v1108%%v1109%%v1110%%v1111%%v1112%%v1113%%v1114%%v1115%%v1116%%v1117%%v1118%%v1119%%v1120%%v1121%%v1122%%v1123%%v1124%%v1125%%v1126%%v1127%%v1128%%v1129%%v1130%%v1131%%v1132%%v1133%%v1134%%v1135%%v1136%%v1137%%v1138%%v1139%%v1140%%v1141%%v1142%%v1143%%v1144%%v1145%%v1146%%v1147%%v1148%%v1149%%v1150%|
ECHO |%v1201%%v1202%%v1203%%v1204%%v1205%%v1206%%v1207%%v1208%%v1209%%v1210%%v1211%%v1212%%v1213%%v1214%%v1215%%v1216%%v1217%%v1218%%v1219%%v1220%%v1221%%v1222%%v1223%%v1224%%v1225%%v1226%%v1227%%v1228%%v1229%%v1230%%v1231%%v1232%%v1233%%v1234%%v1235%%v1236%%v1237%%v1238%%v1239%%v1240%%v1241%%v1242%%v1243%%v1244%%v1245%%v1246%%v1247%%v1248%%v1249%%v1250%|
ECHO |%v1301%%v1302%%v1303%%v1304%%v1305%%v1306%%v1307%%v1308%%v1309%%v1310%%v1311%%v1312%%v1313%%v1314%%v1315%%v1316%%v1317%%v1318%%v1319%%v1320%%v1321%%v1322%%v1323%%v1324%%v1325%%v1326%%v1327%%v1328%%v1329%%v1330%%v1331%%v1332%%v1333%%v1334%%v1335%%v1336%%v1337%%v1338%%v1339%%v1340%%v1341%%v1342%%v1343%%v1344%%v1345%%v1346%%v1347%%v1348%%v1349%%v1350%|
ECHO |%v1401%%v1402%%v1403%%v1404%%v1405%%v1406%%v1407%%v1408%%v1409%%v1410%%v1411%%v1412%%v1413%%v1414%%v1415%%v1416%%v1417%%v1418%%v1419%%v1420%%v1421%%v1422%%v1423%%v1424%%v1425%%v1426%%v1427%%v1428%%v1429%%v1430%%v1431%%v1432%%v1433%%v1434%%v1435%%v1436%%v1437%%v1438%%v1439%%v1440%%v1441%%v1442%%v1443%%v1444%%v1445%%v1446%%v1447%%v1448%%v1449%%v1450%|
ECHO |%v1501%%v1502%%v1503%%v1504%%v1505%%v1506%%v1507%%v1508%%v1509%%v1510%%v1511%%v1512%%v1513%%v1514%%v1515%%v1516%%v1517%%v1518%%v1519%%v1520%%v1521%%v1522%%v1523%%v1524%%v1525%%v1526%%v1527%%v1528%%v1529%%v1530%%v1531%%v1532%%v1533%%v1534%%v1535%%v1536%%v1537%%v1538%%v1539%%v1540%%v1541%%v1542%%v1543%%v1544%%v1545%%v1546%%v1547%%v1548%%v1549%%v1550%|
ECHO |%v1601%%v1602%%v1603%%v1604%%v1605%%v1606%%v1607%%v1608%%v1609%%v1610%%v1611%%v1612%%v1613%%v1614%%v1615%%v1616%%v1617%%v1618%%v1619%%v1620%%v1621%%v1622%%v1623%%v1624%%v1625%%v1626%%v1627%%v1628%%v1629%%v1630%%v1631%%v1632%%v1633%%v1634%%v1635%%v1636%%v1637%%v1638%%v1639%%v1640%%v1641%%v1642%%v1643%%v1644%%v1645%%v1646%%v1647%%v1648%%v1649%%v1650%|
ECHO |%v1701%%v1702%%v1703%%v1704%%v1705%%v1706%%v1707%%v1708%%v1709%%v1710%%v1711%%v1712%%v1713%%v1714%%v1715%%v1716%%v1717%%v1718%%v1719%%v1720%%v1721%%v1722%%v1723%%v1724%%v1725%%v1726%%v1727%%v1728%%v1729%%v1730%%v1731%%v1732%%v1733%%v1734%%v1735%%v1736%%v1737%%v1738%%v1739%%v1740%%v1741%%v1742%%v1743%%v1744%%v1745%%v1746%%v1747%%v1748%%v1749%%v1750%|
ECHO |%v1801%%v1802%%v1803%%v1804%%v1805%%v1806%%v1807%%v1808%%v1809%%v1810%%v1811%%v1812%%v1813%%v1814%%v1815%%v1816%%v1817%%v1818%%v1819%%v1820%%v1821%%v1822%%v1823%%v1824%%v1825%%v1826%%v1827%%v1828%%v1829%%v1830%%v1831%%v1832%%v1833%%v1834%%v1835%%v1836%%v1837%%v1838%%v1839%%v1840%%v1841%%v1842%%v1843%%v1844%%v1845%%v1846%%v1847%%v1848%%v1849%%v1850%|
ECHO |%v1901%%v1902%%v1903%%v1904%%v1905%%v1906%%v1907%%v1908%%v1909%%v1910%%v1911%%v1912%%v1913%%v1914%%v1915%%v1916%%v1917%%v1918%%v1919%%v1920%%v1921%%v1922%%v1923%%v1924%%v1925%%v1926%%v1927%%v1928%%v1929%%v1930%%v1931%%v1932%%v1933%%v1934%%v1935%%v1936%%v1937%%v1938%%v1939%%v1940%%v1941%%v1942%%v1943%%v1944%%v1945%%v1946%%v1947%%v1948%%v1949%%v1950%|
ECHO |%v2001%%v2002%%v2003%%v2004%%v2005%%v2006%%v2007%%v2008%%v2009%%v2010%%v2011%%v2012%%v2013%%v2014%%v2015%%v2016%%v2017%%v2018%%v2019%%v2020%%v2021%%v2022%%v2023%%v2024%%v2025%%v2026%%v2027%%v2028%%v2029%%v2030%%v2031%%v2032%%v2033%%v2034%%v2035%%v2036%%v2037%%v2038%%v2039%%v2040%%v2041%%v2042%%v2043%%v2044%%v2045%%v2046%%v2047%%v2048%%v2049%%v2050%|
ECHO TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT

PAUSE




:END
```

Comment: You might want to consider learning to use the `FOR /L` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these lines:

```
ECHO |%v2001%%v2002%%v2003%%v2004%%v2005%%v2006%%v2007%%v2008%%v2009%%v2010%%v2011%%v2012%%v2013%%v2014%%v2015%%v2016%%v2017%%v2018%%v2019%%v2020%%v2021%%v2022%%v2023%%v2024%%v2025%%v2026%%v2027%%v2028%%v2029%%v2030%%v2031%%v2032%%v2033%%v2034%%v2035%%v2036%%v2037%%v2038%%v2039%%v2040%%v2041%%v2042%%v2043%%v2044%%v2045%%v2046%%v2047%%v2048%%v2049%%v2050%|
```

you need to escape the pipe:

```
ECHO ^|%v2001%%v2002%%v2003%%v2004%%v2005%%v2006%%v2007%%v2008%%v2009%%v2010%%v2011%%v2012%%v2013%%v2014%%v2015%%v2016%%v2017%%v2018%%v2019%%v2020%%v2021%%v2022%%v2023%%v2024%%v2025%%v2026%%v2027%%v2028%%v2029%%v2030%%v2031%%v2032%%v2033%%v2034%%v2035%%v2036%%v2037%%v2038%%v2039%%v2040%%v2041%%v2042%%v2043%%v2044%%v2045%%v2046%%v2047%%v2048%%v2049%%v2050%^|
```

Comment: I went in and added that, and I got the same result.

Comment: Actually, I apologize, I forgot to add them on the end as well. Thank you very much for your assistance.